# Google Nexus 10 doesn't support the optional fields of Camera.Face (leftEye, mouth, rightEye)

Tags: java, android, camera, face-detection, nexus-10

I am now trying to make an App to detect human faces on a Google Nexus 10 using [Camera.FaceDetectionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.FaceDetectionListener.html). The faces have been successfully detected and shown on the screen by drawing rectangles around them.

The problem for me now is that this tablet doesn't support the optional fields of [Camera.Face](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Face.html). Because the value of field "id" always equals to -1, and it's the same result with front and back camera.

Could there be any possible reasons that cause this problem? On the other hand, if anyone knows any device that fully supports all optional fields of Camera.Face? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could there be any possible reasons that cause this problem?

Yes. The device manufacturer decided not to support this feature.

> On the other hand, if anyone knows any device that fully supports all
>   optional fields of Camera.Face?

You should do your own research to find a device that fits your needs.

Comment: By clicking on the check mark below the upvote/downvote buttons on the answer.